# Save .Mat in Every Iterations

Tags: matlab

Im Working on Simulation Dehumidification Process, i should save .Mat file in every loop, my program flowchart is:

```
enter code here 
for  m=9:2:21

  for kk=1:ll
    for jj=1:mm
      for ii=1:nn

           ...
           ...
           ...

      end
    end
 end     

A=min(X-Y)  

end
```

for example
mm=9 then A=1
mm=11 then A=2
..., How i can Plot A with mm?
and How i can Save .Mat file in every mm iteration? Thanks.

> Blockquote
>     %A=(7*1)Matrix %9:2:21=7(Number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save a .mat-file for each iteration the only thing you need to do is to generate a unique filename for each iteration within the loop. This can be done using format strings, for instance in your case something like

```
    filename = sprintf('output_kk=%d_jj=%d_ii=%d.mat', [kk jj ii]);
    save(filename);
```

You have the option to save specific variables by adding them as options to the `save` command. For more about string formatting I'd suggest you check out the `sprintf` documentation.

I'm not sure whether this is the most efficient way to do it. Depending on the number and size of output variables you're interested in you can also create a cell structure and save your data into a new cell for each iteration.